# CLLocationManager update location is not accurate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am using `CLLocationManager` to access the user location the following delegate method return coordinates which are not accurate

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

}
```

Comment: if not accurate then maybe device is in building or there is storm.

Comment: @GeneCode the device is inside a park. But gps points a building opposite to park

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy of the location data.

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
```

You should assign a value to this property that is appropriate for your usage scenario.

**For example** If you need the current location only within a kilometer, you should specify `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer` and not `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`. Determining a location with greater accuracy requires more time and more power.

Comment: Actually, I need to draw a polyline of the user who walks opening my app. While walking CLLocationManager gives wrong coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

[`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423716-locationmanager?language=objc)
is deprecated. It is recommended to use [`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager?language=objc).
It tells the delegate that new location data is available. The most recent location update is at the end of the array `locations`.

---

Following are the properties you can explore:

[**distanceFilter:**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423500-distancefilter) The minimum distance (measured in meters) a device must move horizontally before an update event is generated.

[**desiredAccuracy:**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423836-desiredaccuracy) The accuracy of the location data.

Comment: Actually, I need to draw a polyline of the user who walks opening my app. While walking CLLocationManager gives wrong coordinates.

Comment: `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`  is the highest possible accuracy. you should try setting it. But even then I believe the location can't be perfect to the point. there will always be some scope for error

Comment: Yes but this works in outdoor. But in indoor or the person when entering to a park the location is not accurate

Comment: I believe for this kind of tracking using only `CLLocation` won't suffice, I think you should explore NFC which may require additional hardware setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases to as you said "Not accurate".

1. Not a current location which you are expecting.
2. Little bit difference in latitude and longitude of your current location.

Case 1: Change your current location in your iPhone and then try again to fetch your location.

Case 2: In that case, you should set some values to the location manager's object like desired accuracy and distance filter.

Also, share your code inside this method. Maybe you are doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: See like if Am entering a park my current location points a building and it is moving nearby places when i wait in a place the current location still get updated. You are getting .. ?

Comment: Hmmm, if you have noticed on Google Map many locations do show location nearby road, not of exact place. Suppose you are in a part but Google Map will show get your location of the nearby road.   Got it???

Comment: But i am not using gps option for navigation type